Microchip dsPIC33CK256MP506 SPI Custom word size only transmits first 6 bit values
I'm setting up an SPI (on a dsPIC33CK256MP506) to behave as an synchronous UART (only transmitting as a slave).
Since SPI starts to transmit MSB I start with adding a start bit in front, then 8data bits, 1 stop and 1 idle bit to a total of 11bits.
I setup the SPI3 SPI3CON2Lbits.WLENGTH = 10 (11 bits) and it indeed shifts out 11 bits (on external master clock), but only the first 6 bits I load in SPI3BUFL comes out correctly. The other 5 bits are always 0.
The idle level is low so start bit is 1 and stop + idle is 00.
Initialization of SPI3.
SPI3CON1Lbits.SPIEN  =  0;  // Disable SPI
RPINR29bits.SCK3R    = 64; // RP64 - SCLK IN
RPOR22bits.RP76R     = 11; // RP76 - Dout

SPI3CON1Lbits.DISSDI  =  1; // Disable Data IN
SPI3CON1bits.MSTEN    =  0; // Set SPI to Slave mode
SPI3CON1Lbits.CKP     =  0; // CKP is the same as CPOL
SPI3CON1Lbits.CKE     =  1; // CKE is the inverse of CPHA
SPI3CON1Lbits.SMP     =  0; // 0 when in slave mode
SPI3CON1Lbits.MODE    =  0; // Shall be zero if WLENGTH > 0
SPI3CON2Lbits.WLENGTH = 10; // 1 start + 8 data + 1 stop + 1 Idle bit.

(void volatile)SPI3BUFL; // Clear buffer
(void volatile)SPI3BUFH; // Clear buffer

SPI3IMSKLbits.SPITBEN = 1; // Enable TX Buffer Empty
IFS3bits.SPI3TXIF     = 0; // Clear Tx interrupt flag
IEC3bits.SPI3TXIE     = 1; // Enable TX interrupts
IEC8bits.SPI3IE       = 1; // Enable SPI3 interrupts
SPI3CON1Lbits.SPIEN   = 1; // Enable SPI

As you can see, it is interrupt driven on TX empty.
Here is the ISR.
void __attribute__((interrupt, auto_psv)) _SPI3TXInterrupt(void) {    

    if(SPI3STATLbits.SPITBE == 1) { // Check if TX buffer is empty
        SPI3BUFL = (uint16_t)0b11111111100;
    }

    IFS3bits.SPI3TXIF = 0;
}

In this test I have 1 start bit 8 databits all 1 and 1 stop bit and 1 idle bit.
The result should be 11111111100 but I get 11111100000 (checking on my oscilloscope)
I can change the 6 first bits but never the last 5 bits.
I can't find any examples when the WLENGTH register is used. Does anyone have an answer to this mystery?

"behave as an synchronous UART" - If that's not a typo, then you have a contradiction. "The idle level is low so start bit is 1" - You have these definitions completely inverted. Idle is a Mark condition which is a logical high or 1. Use an oscilloscope on the output of a real (asynchronous) UART, or study a UART datasheet to resolve your confusion.

@sawdust As I said "behaves" in meaning of start, data and stop bits. I'm not intending to do do a full standard UART (since it is asynchronous and I need it to be synchronous). This is a data stream feed to a FPGA and has to be bit synchronous with the FPGA clock. I have explained in my question what I need to do and the expected result with the result I get. I need to understand why the SPI block is ignoring 5 bits of data. It does output 11bits, just that the last 5bits always are 0. So the UART protocol isn't the problem, the SPI setup is.

@Mike As far I understand, AUDEN must be 0 to use WLENGTH. The SPI indeed clocks out 11 bits, but the last 5 bits are always 0, regardless of what I write in SPI3BUFL. It also makes no sense why the 6 first bits are clocked out. If it was 8bits I would suspect some buffer setting being wrong or similar.

@Mike, no worries. Microchip "documentation" has its reputation :)
